combine files and enter file names in excel columns using python
i am processing merging files and inserting file names in excel column but this is not working, can anyone help me with this problem, thank you
here's what I did
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dir_path = 'D:/Test Merge'

files = [a for a in os.listdir(dir_path) if a.endswith('.xlsx')]

sheetname = 'CAPEX (2)'
dfs = []

for file in files:
    file_path = os.path.join(dir_path,file)
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path,sheet_name=sheetname)
        df['filename'] = os.path.basename()
        dfs.append(df)
    except Exception as a:
        print("Not Found")
merged_df = pd.concat(dfs)

merged_df.to_excel(os.path.join('D:/Test Merge','merge_data.xlsx'), index=False)

and this is what the error looks like
raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Hi, welcome to SO! Only printing a string Not Found on any error seems like a bad idea (cf. e.g., here), as it obscures the thing that is going wrong. In your case, each iteration is failing, because os.path.basename expects a path argument. So, at the end of the day, this is just a typo of sorts: os.path.basename() -> os.path.basename(file_path), or just simply: df['filename'] = file.

try this:
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path =r'C:/test_files'
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xlsx'))
df = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_excel(file).assign(file_name=os.path.basename(file)) for file in files],ignore_index=True)


try this :
import os 
import pandas as pd
pathh=r"C:\Users\743622\Downloads\teting excels"
files=[x for x in os.listdir(pathh)]
dfs=[]

for file in files:
    df=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(pathh,file))
    
    df['name']=file
    
    dfs.append(df)
    
merged=pd.concat(dfs)
print(merged.head())  

